# Matplotlib: How to change figsize for double bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a double bar plot in matplotlib using the following code:

```
x = pd.Series(range(12))
y = self.cust_data['Cluster_ID'].value_counts().sort_index()
z = self.cust_data['Cluster_ID_NEW'].value_counts().sort_index()
plt.bar(x + 0.0, y, color = 'b', width = 0.5)
plt.bar(x + 0.5, z, color = 'g', width = 0.5)
plt.legend(['Old Cluster', 'New Cluster'])
plt.savefig("C:\\Users\\utkarsh.a.ranjan\\Documents\\pyqt_data\\generate_results\\bar", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.1)
plt.clf()
```

I want to use the figsize parameter to make the resultant plot bigger in size. This is easy when plotting a single bar plot, but here I am confused as to where to put the figsize parameter.

Comment: if you provided a sample of your data your example could be reproduced https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could set the size with `figsize`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5)) # set the size that you'd like (width, height)
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], label = 'first bar')
plt.bar([10,11,12,13], [0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1], label = 'second bar')
ax.legend(fontsize = 14)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do that follows a more OO approach:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
ax.bar(x + 0.0, y, color = 'b', width = 0.5)
ax.bar(x + 0.5, z, color = 'g', width = 0.5)
ax.legend(['Old Cluster', 'New Cluster'])
fig.savefig("C:\\Users\\utkarsh.a.ranjan\\Documents\\pyqt_data\\generate_results\\bar", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.1)
plt.clf()
```

You also might want to add format to your filename. If not, the format is taken from your rc parameter `savefig.format`, which is usually `png`.

BTW, if you want to stick to your code as much as possible, you can also add the line before your `plt.bar(...)`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
```

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to increase plot size is to simply add this line of code before your code:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 5)
```

You can change the figure size according to your wish.