# Overlapped y axis in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

How to give space for overlapped y axis?

Comment: I don't think you can just do that. You'll have to make the figure bigger, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080743/7746941 or you can try rotating the ticks, with something like `plt.yticks(rotation=70)`. It's hard to get helped without posting some code